# Why RSACryptoServiceProvider VerifyData method is taking 30 seconds when deployed on server

Tags: c#, rsa

The rsa1.VerifyData() method is taking 30 seconds to return the result. The parameter calculation is completed within few milliseconds. I have tried adding the OID mappings in machine.config but no benefit.

```
    public bool VerifyData(string publicKeyXml, string plainData, string base64Signature)
    {
        try
        {

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

            rsa1.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);


            bool isVerified = rsa1.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainData), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), Convert.FromBase64String(base64Signature));


            return isVerified;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.CreateLogInFileS(ex, "VerifyHash", "Exception");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect this is related to some network issue in reaching a Certificate Authority to validate local certificates used by crypto services. After the default timeout (30 sec), by default your OS may use its certificates. Please check if, with network connectivity, it works well. Also, you may have a look with some network tracing tool (eg. ProcMon is quite straightforward to use) to identify any attempt to reach some unavailable resource.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas Sir, is there any mechanism to skip the certificate validation and directly use the OS certificates. Also, since the verify data method is within a web api hosted on IIS, I am unable to find it out to be logged in procmon.

Comment: If you have access on the OS (eg. via RDP), you could download and run ProcMon locally while experiencing the 30sec delay. You could google "disable certificate revocation check" to find out how to skip this check according to your OS. Please take my advice just as a workaround: ideal solution is to grant your server proper access to CA.

Comment: You could compute the SHA256 yourself, and use VerifyHash, that would let you break down the timing between the hashing half and the RSA half.  (FWIW, there's nothing in this code that would touch a network, since it's raw keys, not certificates)